# CSS media query for large screen overwriting media query for small screen

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm in the process of making my new development site mobile responsive but I've noticed some odd behavior that's driving me a little insane. Hopefully someone can point out what I'm doing wrong here. When I'm testing at a small resolution, say 320px width the rules from the 720px width are also being applied and since they're lower in the cascade are taking priority. I've been counteracting this each time with an !important declaration on the smaller size query but I know this can't be correct.

My actual CSS is too large to include but here's an example of what I'm seeing. If I have two DIVs side by side on large tablet/small desktop but want them to be full width and one on top of another on phone:

```
@media screen and (max-width:479px){
     div{width:100%}
}
@media screen and (max-width:1159px) and (min-width:980px){
     div{width:49%;float:left}
     div:first-child{margin-right:2%}
}
```

When I check in 320px through 479px width the rules for the 980-1159 are loaded and I have to use !important declarations as well as set float to none and margin to 0. Why is this happening and am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming all is wrong with it is the ordering of things:

Instead of:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1159px) and (min-width:980px){
```

I changed it to:

```
@media screen and (min-width:980px) and (max-width:1159px){
```

And it seems to be working fine. Resize the result square to see if that is what you are looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/wyyqLmg6/1/

Comment: For some reason resizing the result window doesn't work for me. I did for a brief moment think that may have have been an issue but I've tried it both ways and it still loads the same. This is part of a Wordpress template, I wonder if it's possible for some plugin or script to affect the media query order but that shouldn't be possible right?

I've also tried moving the larger resolution query to the top so the small resolution query takes priority but this only removes the need for the !important declarations and I still have to null or reset the unneeded values.

Comment: Hi, since that preview area might not get to be over 980px wide, I changed it to 480 just for testing purposes. Can you check whether it works for you? https://jsfiddle.net/wyyqLmg6/1/